# Setting decimal separator doesn't work

Tags: java, string-formatting

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setDecimalSeparator(' ');
DecimalFormat nf = new DecimalFormat();
nf.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
tf.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(new FormatStringConverter(nf)));
```

I wanted to change the separator from `.` to   (Space).
But I still have a `.`
What is wrong with that?

Comment: Are you using JavaFX?

Comment: I am sorry. I used it in the context, yes